# Why can't I use ALTER to set the default on a column?

Tags: mysql-5.7, alter-table, timestamp

Long story short, I have a table with a TIMESTAMP column where I want to make the default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (default currently is 1971-01-01 00:00:00).
This is part of a WordPress plugin, and so performance is important here.

I originally used a query like this:
`ALTER TABLE wp_ewwwio_images ALTER updated SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

This was speedy, and worked a treat, but now I'm finding it doesn't work on all MySQL servers. Notably, we've run into trouble with sites running MariaDB 10.1 and MySQL 5.7, where it says something like this:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html the syntax looks fine. At least, the syntax in the manual is identical to that for version 8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

The alternative is to use this:
`ALTER TABLE wp_ewwwio_images MODIFY updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

This works fine for the affected server versions, but is much slower; ALTER is near instant, MODIFY takes 3-4 seconds on a table with 260k records on SSDs. Who knows what it looks like if some poor sap is on spinning disks still...

So I know how to work around said "issue", but what I really want to know is, what IS the actual problem here? Why don't older MySQL (and MariaDB) versions accept the ALTER syntax when the docs are identical?

Comment: Just a question : Was strict SQL mode enabled on the servers that did not work ???

Comment: On the one server that I have access to, that does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get a bit more insight from Sergei at MariaDB. Specifically, he noted that the error is with "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", which is what I suspected also:

> In MySQL before 8.0.13 and in MariaDB before 10.2.1 one can only use a
> signed number in ALTER ... SET DEFAULT.
>
> This is arguably a bug. But it's unlikely that you'll get it fixed in
> MySQL 5.7 (and MariaDB 10.1 is beyond EOL already).

In other words, one could use the `ALTER column SET DEFAULT` syntax just fine if you were setting it to a specific value, like I did originally in setting the default to "1971-01-01 00:00:00". But if you want to set the default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on those older versions, you'd need to use the MODIFY/CHANGE syntax instead.

Based on the docs, that does indeed seem a bug, but if anyone has additional insight/references, feel free to share.